# Kafka Connector for Snowflake keeps failing

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I start the Kafka Connector I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 3 error(s):
snowflake.url.name: Cannot connect to Snowflake
snowflake.user.name: Cannot connect to Snowflake
snowflake.private.key: Cannot connect to Snowflake
```

I have tried setting url in following two ways:

```
snowflake.url.name=<ID assigned to me>.snowflakecomputing.com:443
snowflake.url.name=<My user id>.us-west-2.snowflakecomputing.com:443
```

I've set snowflake.user.name as:

```
snowflake.user.name=<My login id>
```

Not sure exactly how to set 'snowflake.private.key'. I copied contents of:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

After removing all new line characters so the value looks something like this:

```
snowflake.private.key=MIIEowIBAAKCAQEApM9bYyleCC+......... <long string>
```

I also tried to run the following command in Snowflake worksheet under **SECURITYADMIN** role but it keeps failing:

```
alter user <my user id> set rsa_public_key='MIIEowIBAAKCAQEApM9bYyleCC...';
```

Error message:

```
SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on user
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it worked when I used the 'ACCOUNTADMIN' role.

Answer (score 1):

snowflake.url.name should match the account name that you use to get to Snowflake via the UI, not your login name.  This account name might have a region in the url, as well, which should be included.  For example, `xyzcompany.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443`.

```
snowflake.url.name=<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com:443
```

I would make sure that you are setting your role in the correct place in the UI worksheet.  Easiest way to check is to run a `SELECT CURRENT_ROLE();` command.  You can also just run `USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;` in the worksheet to make sure you are set correctly.  That role should have permissions to alter user parameters.

Comment: I am doing EXACTLY same as how you've described here but it's still not working. Wondering if it's because I am using a '30 day trial' version.